# asp.net mvc IDataErrorInfo validation when using ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, idataerrorinfo

I have used IDataErrorInfo Validation for my Model.
But when I use these model classes inside a view model, the validation does not happen.

sample viewmodel below

```
public class CategoryViewModel    
{
    // Category class with IDataErrorInfo
    public Category category { set; get; }

    // Subcategory class with IDataErrorInfo
    public IList<SubCategory> subcategory { set; get; }
}
```

Now, if Category or Subcategory classes are directly used as models for view, the validation works fine. But, if CategoryViewModel is used, no validation occurs.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov : 

well, if it does not work with child properties, IDataErrorInfo seems pretty useless, except for very simple forms.
I cant seem to get any article which discusses on best practices for validation, something which compares IDataErrorInfo and DataAnnotations.
1. Do you think it it is better to go with DataAnnotaions since most of my forms use ViewModels like one above?
2. would it not be a bad practice to use dataanotations wrt separation of concerns, since I will be doing a lot of validations in the controller, rather that view or model?.

Comment: I think that DataAnnotations are better. You should not do any validation in the controller. With DataAnnotations you use only attributes on your view models. For more advanced validation scenarios use FluentValidation as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) doesn't work with child properties. You will need to implement this interface by the view model you are binding to (`CategoryViewModel`). It is also [considered as bad practice](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/01/31/using-idataerrorinfo-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-should-be-considered-worst-practice.aspx). As an alternative you might look at [DataAnnotations](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) or [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) for more advanced validation scenarios.